# Tailwindcss not reflecting the styles in PHP

Tags: php, css, tailwind-css

Hi I am trying to add tailwindcss to my php project, very basic.
It seems that I have managed to install it and the style.css which I generate is showing in the network monitor, as 200.
But neverthless, I don't see tailwind reflecting in my project.
I have read through topic on stack overflow and seek at other location, can't find the answer, or if the solutions for others don't seems to work.
This is how my code looks.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.{html,js,php}"],

  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Can someone assist to get it working?
Thanks,
BM.

I am trying to find a solution, why tailwindcss is not working in a very basic php, which experienced can help me with the solution, as I am not able to find the solution.

Comment: Could you provide details about how you are running Tailwind? Are you using the CLI? Consider checking you are loading the output CSS and not an input CSS. Consider checking that the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the files that use Tailwind classes.

Comment: This is the code I am running: npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o ./templates/style.css --watch
Folder structure:
AB
>templates
->header
->footer
->style.css
index.php
input.css
{}package-lock.json
{}package.json
JS tailwind.config.js

Comment: Consider checking you are loading the output CSS and not an input CSS. Consider checking that the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the files that use Tailwind classes.

Comment: This is what the way I am linking:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../templates/style.css">

Comment: I can't quite discern your folder structure in your comment – consider editing your question with your file structure and format it for clarity. Consider checking that the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the files that use Tailwind classes.